# CTE and Substring/CHARINDEX

Tags: sql, sql-server, substring, common-table-expression

I thought CTE was kinda like a temporary table where I could reference to from the following query.
I'm confused on the error I am getting ONLY when using the `WHERE` of the last query.

`Certifiedby` field has `name:date:id:`.
I am checking to see if `certifiedby` is `NULL`, if so make `CERT_DATE`=1/1/1970, otherwise extract the date from `Certifiedby` into `CERT_DATE`.

If I run the first part of the query up to `SELECT * FROM Certified`
I get the expected results and the `CERT_DATE` are all correct.

But when I add/execute the `WHERE CERT_DATE BETWEEN '2/1/2023' AND '2/22/2023'` I get the error

> Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.

I thought once `Certified` was created I could reference it's data? From the error it seems it's still trying to extract the date?

Clues? thank you

[SQLFiddle Sample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/079f0/3)

```sql
WITH Certified AS (
    select
        certifiedBy,
        CASE WHEN certifiedBy IS NULL  THEN '1/1/1970' ELSE SUBSTRING(certifiedBy, CHARINDEX(':', certifiedBy, 1) + 1, CHARINDEX(':', certifiedBy, 
        CHARINDEX(':', certifiedBy, 1) + 1) - CHARINDEX(':', certifiedBy, 1) - 1)  
        END AS CERT_DATE
    From dbo.PO_Orders 
    WHERE poreference = 'shev'  
    )
SELECT * FROM Certified 
WHERE CERT_DATE BETWEEN '2/1/2023' AND '2/22/2023' 
ORDER BY CERT_DATE
```

I'm expecting to get back all records with `CERT_DATE` within the date range.

Comment: It is entirely possible that including an outer condition changes the execution plan such that your `case` is evaluated before `WHERE poreference = 'shev'`.

Comment: That format for specifying date literals is ambiguous and SQL Server and likely to create unexpected results.

Comment: What version of SQL Server is this? SQL Server 2022 has a feature that lets us significantly simplify the code if you can use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the `CERT_DATE` column in the CTE **IS NOT A DATE**. It's a **STRING** that happens to look kinda like a date to people with certain cultural backgrounds... but the computer and database **only see the string**. Therefore the `BETWEEN` operator is doing an ordinal comparison between strings, rather than date comparisons.

There's an important concept to understand about date and datetime values when working with computers:

> **Cultural/internationalization issues mean converting to and from strings and date (or numeric) values is far more expensive and error-prone than we generally expect. It's something to avoid as much as possible.**

This has a number of implications:

1. Date and Datetime values in the server are not stored as strings at all internally; it is not a human-readable format
2. Using strings to do date operations is generally the slowest and least-reliable option
3. There are certain preferred formats for date literals in your code that often do not match your own cultural background. On SQL Server you have these three options, and you should not deviate from them:

   `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss[.fff]`
   `yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss[.fff]`
   `yyyyMMdd`

With that in mind, we can re-write the original code like this to follow better practice and get expected results:

```
WITH Certified AS (
    SELECT certifiedBy,
        coalesce(datefromparts(  
           right(SUBSTRING(CertifiedBy, 1, charindex(':', certifiedby, charindex('/', certifiedby))-1),4), -- year  
           REPLACE(SUBSTRING(certifiedBy, CHARINDEX(':', certifiedBy, 1) + 1, 2),'/',''), -- month
           REPLACE(SUBSTRING(certifiedBy, CHARINDEX('/', certifiedBy, 1) + 1, 2),'/','') -- day
        ),'19700101') as CERT_DATE
    FROM dbo.PO_Orders 
    WHERE  poreference = 'shev'  
)
SELECT  * 
FROM Certified 
WHERE CERT_DATE >= '20230201' AND CERT_DATE < '20230223' 
ORDER BY CERT_DATE
```

See it here:

> https://dbfiddle.uk/TUBKuAr6

Of course, even better if you can update the application to capture this as a real datetime column at INSERT/UPDATE time. That will perform better by multiple orders of magnitude.

Comment: I see....Thank you all, Always learning :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to evaluate your derived date as either a date for format it yyyyMMdd.  You cannot really compare M/d/yyyy.

in SQL parlance,

```sql
SELECT CASE WHEN '1/1/1970' < '10/1/1902' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END;


result:

-----------
1
```

And, as far as CTE's go, they're not very different from sub-queries, except you can also do cool things like recursive queries.

In your SQL Fiddle, a query that works is:

```sql
WITH Certified AS
(
    SELECT certifiedBy,
        CONVERT(DATE, CASE WHEN certifiedBy IS NULL THEN '19700101'
            ELSE
                SUBSTRING (
                    certifiedBy, CHARINDEX (':', certifiedBy, 1) + 1,
                    CHARINDEX (':', certifiedBy, CHARINDEX (':', certifiedBy, 1) + 1) - CHARINDEX (':', certifiedBy, 1) - 1
                )
        END) AS CERT_DATE
    FROM dbo.PO_Orders
    WHERE poreference = 'shev'
)
SELECT *
FROM Certified
WHERE CERT_DATE  BETWEEN '20230201' AND '20230222' 
ORDER BY CERT_DATE;
```

Note: removed dashes from the DATE strings per @joel-coehoorn's comment. Apparently certain regions will flip month and day when using `'yyyy-MM-dd'` format.

Comment: `2023-02-01` is actually still not a fully correct date format for SQL Server. See here: https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-dating-responsibly